# Add existing UIViewControllers without nib files to UITabBarController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have two UIViewController classes called MeasurementsVC.swift and OutfitBuilder.swift. However, I do not have nib files for these UIViewControllers. I want to load them into a UITabBarController so I can switch between the two UIViewControllers. Based off of [the swift swift tutorial](http://makeapppie.com/2014/09/09/swift-swift-using-tab-bar-controllers-in-swift/), I have the following in my AppDelegate file

```
    func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let myVC1: UIViewController = OutfitBuilderVC()
    let myVC2: UIViewController = MeasurementsVC()
    let controllers = [myVC1,myVC2]
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "tshirtIcon.jpg")
    let image2 = UIImage(named: "measureTape.jpg")
    myVC1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "tshirtIcon", image: image1, tag: 1)
    myVC2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "measureTape", image: image2, tag:2)
    return true
}
```

All that shows up now is a blue screen with a gray tab at the bottom. I think the problem may lie with the lines

```
    let myVC1: UIViewController = OutfitBuilderVC()
    let myVC2: UIViewController = MeasurementsVC()
```

How should I be calling these existing UIViewControllers? Both the UIViewControllers can run on their own. I created them in separate projects as the only UIViewController.

Comment: What if you try: let myVC1 = OutfitBuilderVC()

Comment: Where are the views of these controllers made? In code?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not just making the tab bar from the default app templates and using storyboards?

Comment: @MikeTaverne I tried that, and I get the same blue screen with the gray tab.

Comment: @rdelmar The views of the controllers are made in the viewdidload section of the respective viewcontrollers. (in code)

Comment: @Bluehound I wanted to try doing this all programmatically, because I had previously written the two viewcontrollers. The Viewcontrollers also have some functionalities that I thought were more easily implemented in code, such as having a horizontally rotating UIPickerView

Comment: Since you're seeing something, I assume you've created the window somewhere? Which template did you start with? Is there a default storyboard that came with the template? If so, do you have anything in it?

Comment: Those lines are fine, if you're making your views in code. I tested you code, and it worked fine for me. You might need to show what you're doing in your to child controllers.

Comment: @rdelmar The issue ended up being a combination of not explicitly setting the background color for the two viewcontrollers and the sizing of the images loaded into the tabbarcontroller. After fixing that, everything works beautifully. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well you are working with a storyboard is that correct?

If you are working with a storyboard you just have to ctrl drag a line with your mouse from your UITabBarController to your UIViewControllers... (One line to OutfitBuilderVC(), another one to MeasurementsVC()) And in the small black options Menu that appears after releasing your mouse drop over one of the UIViewControllers you just click on Relationship Segue -> view controllers.

After that you can erase all the code you you have written in AppDelegate, because the storyboard handles everything for you... There you can also define icons and Titles of your vcs...

This method you are doing was actually, I think in the old XCode 3 when no storyboards where there. But today you should do it with a storyboard

Comment: I'm not using the storyboard right now. I'm going to end up having around 11 or 12 separate viewcontrollers, with some functionalities that I couldn't figure out using the storyboard. The code works just fine, it was actually a combination of an issue with the size of the images of the UITabBarButtons and not explicitly setting the backgroundcolor for each viewcontroller. I will keep this in mind if I decide to use a storyboard for other apps later on. Thanks.